# logitech flow uage - do i need two receivers?

Tags: logitech-mouse, logitech-unifying-receiver

im trying to use the logitech flow feature, and it might be a stupid question but i was looking at many tutorials and still couldnt find an answer for that.

one of the requirements is that my mouse and keyboard to be connected to my devices. i get it, but does it mean it should be connected at the same time, or that it was once paired in the past?

i mean - do i need to have 2 unifying receivers connected to my 2 devices?

thanks for any help, im just trying to make sure thats what i need before buying another receiver

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes you do. You can use the unify adapter to connect multiple devices to one computer. But in order to use Logitech Flow, you'll have to use another unify adapter for the second computer.